# CakePHP: Add/alter/disable validations in admin context only

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model, controller

In CakePHP model validation is usually static. I use [Prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) to set up the admin area of my app, but I need to add/alter/disable certain validations of my model to make it work for me. How can I go about it?

One specific example would be that guest frontend users have an integer limit validation for one field that is ignored for admin users in the admin context.

Answer (score 2):

You can [dynamically change validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#dynamically-change-validation-rules) in the model using the `ModelValidator` object directly. You can do this in the [`beforeValidate`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforevalidate) callback to have it done on every instance of your model before the actual validation.

There's no built in way in models to find out whether you're in the admin context or not, though, so you will have to pass this information in from your controller. You can archieve this by adding a public variable (i.e. `isAdmin`) to your model and set it in the [`beforeFilter()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks) callback of your Controller depending on whether or not you're in admin context before every action.

A working example would include these parts:

Controller:

```
class MyController extends AppController
{
    function beforeFilter()
    {
        /* If we're in admin context, set the isAdmin variable of MyModel */
        if (isset($this->request->params['admin']) && $this->request->params['admin']) {
            $this->MyModel->isAdmin = true;
        }
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class MyModel extends AppModel
{

    /**
     * @var array Validation rules
     */
    public $validate = array(
        'my_field' => array(
            'myMaxRule' => array(
                'rule' => array('comparison', '<=', 10),
                'message' => 'You are not allowed to enter more than 10.',
            ),
        ),
    );

    /**
     * @var bool Whether the model is currently used in admin context
     */
    public $isAdmin = false;

    public function beforeValidate()
    {
        /* Remove validation rules not needed in admin */
        if ($this->isAdmin) {
            $validator = $this->validator();

            /* Do what has to be done to your validation rules */
            $validator->remove('my_field', 'myMaxRule');
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the rule `myMaxRule` is removed from the validation rules in admin context only. You could use the same method to alter existing rules or add new ones.